# What is the proper process on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I posted a lengthy question on the board and received a number of comments from people helping me. I've since narrowed the issue down to its roots but still have an issue.

Should I totally post a new question or should I *Edit* my existing question?

Comment: If you didn't receive any answers, you can edit the question into shape so it can be answered. That's the purpose of the comments, to request clarification so a post can be improved.

Comment: Editing is fine but remove all those "EDIT"s. The full edit history is available for those who need to know, and in a clear, stand-alone question they only distract.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The primary concern with major edits is that they might invalidate existing answers. If your question doesn't have any answers yet, or if it does but they would still be applicable to the edited version of your question, go ahead and edit it. If there are answers that would be invalidated by your edit, then you should probably ask a new question instead.

However, if your initial question was unclear or too broad and there are answers that don't apply to the clarified/focused version, I'd say you should still edit it then - that's their own fault for answering before the question was ready for it.